# Selecting the lowest value with a grouping

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find the closest job title an employee had to when a ticket was created. My employees table keeps all changes to an employee i.e. manager change, location etc. This is the query I've written;

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(t.created, e.valid_from) "diff",
    t.ticket_id, 
    t.assignee_id, 
    t.created AS 'ticket_created',
    u.user_id,
    u.email,
    e.valid_from,
    ...
    ...
    ...
FROM tickets t
JOIN users u ON t.assignee_id = u.user_id
JOIN employees e ON u.email = e.email
```

This will give a row for each employee change. How can I narrow this down to only select the smallest positive integer from the DATEDIFF? This will allow me to get the single closest job title to ticket creation.

Example output right now;

```
ticket_id diff ticket_created job_title email
111       2    20-04-18       XYZ       a@a.com
111       5    25-04-18       YYZ       a@a.com
111      -30   04-01-18       ABC       a@a.com
```

My desired output is to only keep the first row as it's the lowest positive integer in the diff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this - get only those records for which DATEDIFF will return positive results (bigger than zero), then sort by the actual DATEDIFF and get the first (smallest) one of them:

```
SELECT 
    t.ticket_id, 
    t.assignee_id, 
    t.created AS 'ticket_created',
    u.user_id,
    u.email,
    (SELECT e.job_title FROM employees e 
      WHERE u.email = e.email AND t.created > e.valid_from
      ORDER BY DATEDIFF(t.created, e.valid_from) LIMIT 1
    ) AS valid_from,
    ...
    ...
    ...
FROM tickets t
JOIN users u ON t.assignee_id = u.user_id
```